# Getting confidence intervals on probabilities when doing ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, ordinal

I have a data frame (training) that contains the following columns:

```
       GPAGrpd    Subj1.Grade
1       [0,2)          6
2       [0,2)          6
3       [3,4.3]        1
4       [0,2)          6
5       [2,3)          2
6       [3,3.7)        3
```

I have run the following commands:

```
 Res.clm <- clm(GPAGrpd ~ Subj1.Grade,data=training)
 summary(Res.clm)
 newdat <- data.frame(
      Subj1.Grade = rep(1:6, each = 200),
      GPAGrpd = factor(rep(1:4, each = 300))
 )
 newdat <- cbind(newdat, predict(Res.clm, newdata=newdat, se.fit=TRUE,
          interval=TRUE, type="prob"))
```

However, I get an error message that states: `Error in predict.clm(Res.clm, newdata = newdat, se.fit = TRUE, interval = TRUE,  : 
  response factor 'GPAGrpd' has new levels`

Comment: Yes, it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my error by defining newdat as shown below:

```
    newdat <- data.frame(
      Subj1.Grade = rep(1:6, 200),
      GPAGrpd = factor(rep(1:4, each=300), 
                   labels = c("[0,2)","[2,3)","[3,3.7)","[3.7,4.3]"))
    )
```

It turns out that I do need GPAGrpd when I am trying to plot the results of my predict call. Thanks for your help.